# The cardinality of the set 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $S(m)$ be the sum of decimal digits of a natural number $m$.

Is there a closed form expression for the cardinality of the following set:
$$A(n)=\left \{ (a,b,c)\in\mathbb{N}^3\ |\ 1\le a<b<c,\ a+b+c=n,\ S(a)=S(b)=S(c) \right \}?$$

Comment: Anything related to which base you're using (such as the sum of digits) is inherently difficult to find a closed form for, because our algebra does not see base.

Comment: I would add to the answer of @Arthur that, usually, this kind of problem is very closed on itself, sometimes good for training, olympiads and so, Very seldom linked to great mathematical issues unless the base is particular (base two, base three, base a power of two...)

Answer (score 0):

**Partial solution**

Note that 
$$S(x) \equiv x \pmod{9}$$

Then
$$S(n) \equiv n \equiv a+b+c \equiv S(a)+S(b)+S(c) \equiv 3S(a) \pmod{9}$$

This means that when $3 \nmid n$ we have 
$$A(n)=0$$

When $3|n$ writing $n=9k+3r$ where $r \in \{0,1,2\}$, by the above argument we must have 
$$a \equiv b \equiv c \equiv r \pmod{9}$$

Therefore 
$$a=9a'+r \\
b=9b'+r \\
c=9c'+r$$
and hence $A(n)$ is the number of ways of writing
$$k=a'+b'+c' \\
1 \leq a' < b' <c'$$ and $S(9a'+r)=S(9b'+r)=S(9c'+r)$....

Comment: If $k_1<k_2,$ then the the number of ways of writing $k_1=a'+b'+c'$ $(1\le a'+b'+c')$ is less or equal to the he number of ways of writing $k_2=a'+b'+c$', but, for instance, $|A(1236)|=1237$ and $|A(1239)|=1228$.

Comment: $4+22+1210 = 1236$

Comment: @Tzara_T'hong Yes, I dropped some $S$ in the second case, the problem is trickier here...